# Java - How to select generic class type "on-the-go"

Tags: java, class, if-statement, generics, declaration

I implemented a generic class, and I want to create a variable with a specific type, by the user choice.
I want that no matter what the user choose, the name of the variable will be the same.

What I've got so far:

```
public class MyGeneric <T>
{
...
}
```

main:

```
if(choice==1)
     MyGeneric<Integer> item = new MyGeneric<Integer>();
else
     MyGeneric<String> item = new MyGeneric<String>();
```

I know that declaration within `if` is forbidden.

What can I do?

---

The reason to do that is [that](https://codeshare.io/2jqeDG).

The first option is more readable and "generic"..

Comment: Step 1: understand what generics are, and what they aren't.

Comment: Declaration of a variable within an `if-statement` is not "forbidden", it just limits the scope.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Whatever you are trying to do, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @CraigR8806 - yeah I know.. I meant it giving me an error...

Comment: @khelwood I edit for you..take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to do:

```
MyGeneric<?> item;
if (choice == 1) {
  item = new MyGeneric<Integer>();
} else {
  item = new MyGeneric<String>();
}
```

But the point is: when you start using generics this way ... you loose all their advantages. The **essence** of generics is to give you a certain amount of **type safety** which can be enforced by the compiler.

Your idea to use the "same item" no matter what kind of generic type is really used *contradicts* that intention. You can as well then **forget** about using generics, and simply use Object all over the place.

In other words: the *concrete* generic type used is an **essential** part of the "type" of item. The one only valid use case I see here would more look like:

```
MyGeneric<? extends Number> item;
if (choice == 1) {
  item = new MyGeneric<Integer>();
} else {
  item = new MyGeneric<Float>();
}
```

( where you use some sort of *constraint* on item which can be fulfilled in different ways )

Comment: I dont think so. You see - it **makes** a difference if you have a list of Integer or a List of strings for example. You only add integers to the first list, and you only add strings to the second one. In that sense, I think the first command from Andy is kinda spot on: you should first understand generics better; maybe you can then ask a better question ... or rework your design accordingly.

Comment: Make sence..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that in Java there is a thing called type erasure when using generics (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). They are not available at runtime.

In reality if you really want to know the type inside `MyGeneric`, you have to store the `MyGeneric` type inside `MyGeneric` class. Something like:

```
class MyGeneric{
private Class type; // (as an instance variable of MyGeneric). 
}
```

Then affect the type in your if.